# Auto switch to the active input port on HP Envy 4k monitor

Tags: kvm

I've a HP Envy 27" 4K monitor which I use with both my home and work laptops. The problem is my work laptop connects via hdmi cable and the personal laptop (Mac Book Pro 2017) connects via USB-C. So I've to manually switch monitor's input mode every-time I change computers. At a time, I've only one computer connected to the monitor.

1. Is there a way to activate auto switching in the monitor?
2. If not, does there exist any external solutions (like a KVM switch) so I don't have to fiddle with buttons on the monitor. I've found one such switch ([https://www.amazon.com/Displayport-Digital-Converter-Adapter-Projector/dp/B01MZ432JO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MZ432JO)) but this only has HDMI ports.

Note: Preferably something under $50

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hardware Recs! It generally helps if you post a **price limit** so we can make better recommendations.

Comment: @bennett Yeo thanks, I would prefer something under $50.